# How come this and _this reference different instances of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that can be simplified like this:

```
Captcha = function(el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    _this = this;

    captchas.push(this);
};


Captcha.prototype.render = function(grecaptcha){
    console.log(this.el.dom[0]);
    console.log(_this.el.dom[0])
};
```

The class is intantiated twice with two different DOM-elements passed in as el.

Render is run when a global callbackfunction is run.

```
captchas = [];

//We need  this for captchas.
window.CaptchaCallback = function(){
  app.captchas.forEach(function(capt){
    capt.grecaptcha = grecaptcha;
    capt.render();
  });
};
```

For some reason, `this.el.dom[0]` references the two different elements, but `_this.el.dom[0]` always references the last instance of the class, why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How is it that you intend the `_this` variable to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left off `var` when you initialized `_this`:

```
var Captcha = function(el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    var _this = this; // don't forget var!

    captchas.push(this);
};
```

Your code was therefore creating a global variable, not a local one.

Of course, it's local to that constructor function, so it won't be visible outside anyway. You could make `_this` a property of the constructed object:

```
    this._this = this;
```

but that doesn't make a lot of sense, since you'd need `this` to find `_this` anyway.

Comment: Then calling `render` will throw

Comment: yes, that's the intention of the last part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't declare `_this` with the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword, a global variable is implicitly declared. Your constructor code then equivalent to:

```
var _this;
Captcha = function(el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    _this = this;

    captchas.push(this);
};
```

Because it's global, `_this` always holds the value of the last instance created.